# C signal: segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c

I am learning C, and I am facing this error.
Why I cannot pass a pointer to the funcion as `change(&p_x);` and only `change(&x);` works? Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>

void change(int *p_xa) // GET ERROR HERE signal: segmentation fault (core dumped)
{
    *p_xa = 999;
}
    
int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    int * p_x = &x;

    *p_x = 2;

    change(&p_x); // cannot do this

    printf("x is: %d \n", *p_x);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`change` has a parameter of type `int *`.

The call passes `&p_x`. The type of `p_x` is `int *`. The type of `&p_x` is `int **`. That is the wrong type for the parameter. Passing `&p_x` passes the address of `p_x`, but you want to pass the address of `x`.

Pass `p_x`, not `&p_x`. The value of `p_x` is the address of `x`.

Enable warnings in your compiler and elevate them to errors. With Clang, start with `-Wmost -Werror`. With GCC, start with `-Wall -Werror`. With MSVC, start with `/W3 /WX`. When you do this, the compiler will warn you when an argument is an incorrect type for a declared parameter.

Comment: what `int **` means?

Comment: `T *` is a pointer to a `T`, whatever type `T` is. `T **` is a pointer to a pointer to a `T`. `T ***` is a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a `T`. `T *[]` is an array of pointers to a `T`. `T (*)[]` is a pointer to an array of `T`.

Comment: `int` is an integer. `int *` is a pointer to an integer. `int **` is a pointer to a pointer to an integer. `int ***` is a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to an integer. You can go on, but three asterisks in a row is about the limit of what actually makes sense in real world programs. Oh, and do switch on those warnings as errors. They really help you find stuff before it turns into much worse.

Comment: many thanks for your explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're taking a pointer as a parameter, you must also pass it when you call the function(you are passing the pointer of the pointer)

Comment: could you proviede an example how to fix it?

Comment: @Radex just don't put & before the pointer when calling the function